# it doesn't apper add import java.util.Scanner

Tags: java

I'm learning to "code", when i try to write the class Scanner it doesnt recognize the word, in the class that I'm taking shows that I need to add import java util scanner, but it doesn't appear in my options when a press right click,

the same problem happens with "var"

Thank you so much for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2zil.png)

Comment: Java is a case-sensitive language. `scanner` should be `Scanner`.

Comment: While we're at the subject, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase; class names are written in PascalCase; constants are written in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE and package names in alllowercase.

Comment: Also, the class name is "Scanner", not "Scarnner".

Comment: Links to images of code are not useful. Please edit your question to include your code as (formatted) text.

Comment: "it doesn't appear in my options when a press right click,". So what? You can still type it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computers tend to be quite picky when it comes to correctness.

You wrote 
Sca**r**nner scanner = new **s**canner(System.in)

What you want is:

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)

Generally when programming, double checking things like this is important when problems arrise.

Comment: Thank you I've noticed that! i have more questions!